# Maple tree, drooping leaves. Can I help it look Fuller?

Tags: trees

Admittedly, I'm a new first time home owner. We have this maple in our front yard (Raleigh, NC). The leaves are droopy and it looks hollowed out in the center.

I've tried various watering, more water, less water....doesn't have much of an impact. I've given it a perticide/fertilizer combo that my neighbor recommended (she's got a beauty of a maple).

Would pruning the lower branches help at all? Any ideas?

Thanks![image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: The mulch around the base of the tree looks to be too high (maples are especially sensitive to this). The mulch should not touch the trunk and, as it gets close to the tree, should be no higher than the root flare of the trunk (where the tree trunk widens as the roots begin) because it can be a vector for disease. Mulch that is too high can actually kill a maple and other species of trees. More, closer photos of the bark, base of the trunk, and leaves would be very helpful to us.

Comment: @jurp thanks for the insight. Updated original post with new photos. First is trunk as it was, second with the mulch pulled back.   The first leaf photo shows some that look like they are getting eaten. Added any traps at base of tree since I saw ants. Second is just the drooping leaves. Thanks for any further help.

Comment: Looks like you have a red maple (Acer rubrum) or a cultivar of that species. I don't like that depressed area at the base of the trunk (second new picture). You should definitely remove the mulch from there and the rest of the trunk to the root flare (and do this on your other trees, like the river birch in the background of one of the photos). After you remove the mulch, see if the depressed area is spongy and/or wet. You may have a canker of other disease.

Comment: @Jurp. Thanks for your expertise. The depressed area is solid, so hopefully not canker or disease. Let me know if you have any other thoughts. If not, I guess my next step is to call a local arborist to come check it out. If (s)he has any insights I'll be sure to post them. Thanks again!    PS - good eye on the bitch in the background :)

Comment: If that bark area is on the south  ( or south-west) side , it could be mild "sun scald" caused by winter sun . There are paper-like wraps to protect the bark.

Comment: Since it's solid, the depressed area could be a callus over an old wound. It and the callus directly above it could be the result of a close encounter with a riding mower when the tree was much younger. Good news that it's not a canker!

Comment: @blacksmith37 it's on the east side of the tree. I guess that rules out sunscald. Thanks for the idea though!